# SAS: How to delete word between two specific position?

Tags: sas

data:

```
Hell_TRIAL21_o World
Good Mor_Trial9_ning
```

How do I remove the `_TRIAL21_` and `_TRIAL9_`?

What I did was I find the position of the first _ and the second _. Then I want to compress from the first _ and second _. But the compress function is not available to do so. How?

```
x = index(string, '_');
if (x>0) then do;
    y = x+1; 
    z = find(string, '_', y);
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PERL regular expressions are a good way of identifying these sort of strings.  `call prxchange` is the function that will remove the relevant characters. It requires `prxparse` beforehand to create the search and replace parameters.

I've used `modify` here to amend the existing dataset, obviously you may want to use `set` to write out to a new dataset and test the results first.

```
data have;
input string $ 30.;
datalines;
Hell_TRIAL21_o World
Good Mor_Trial9_ning
;
run;


data have;
modify have;
regex = prxparse('s/_.*_//'); /* identify and remove anything between 2 underscores */
call prxchange(regex,-1,string);
run;
```

Or to create a new variable and dataset, just use `prxchange` (which doesn't require `prxparse`).

```
data want;
set have;
new_string = prxchange('s/_.*_//',-1,string);
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

Text= " Hell_TRIAL21_o World Good Mor_Trial9_ning"

```
var= catx("",scan(text,1,"_"),"__",scan(text,3,"_"),"_", scan(text,5,"_"))
```

Note that the length of variable `var` may not be desirable to your case.Remember to adjust accordingly.

Comment: Good solution.
CATX() function add a delimiter, defined in the first position, also removes leading and trailing blanks.
Hence, if you don't need any delimiter, you should use CATS() function, instead of defining delimiter as "".
Also remember that cat functions (cat catt cats catx) have 200 as standard length.
Anyway Yumi, you can achieve the same result in several way.
Take a look at the complete list of string functions in sas.